# Rendering a Bootstrap Component Using JSX

Tags: reactjs, button, components, reactstrap

Editing for clarity: I cannot figure out how to dynamically create Boostrap Components using JSX in a react app. End goal is to get the new button in the "newBtnSpace" div when the first button is clicked. I have tried using show.hide methods, but those need to be hard coded. Trying to create buttons based off an array. code:

./components/newBSBtnSpaceFunc.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { Button } from 'reactstrap'

    export default function NewBSBtnFunc() {
    let BtnArray = ["red", "blue", "green"].map((btn) => {
        return React.createElement(
            Button,
            {variant: 'primary'},
            'New Button',
            {id: "newBtn"},
             btn
            )   
           }
```

./components/BSBtn.js

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react'
     import { Button } from 'reactstrap'
     import NewBSBtnFunc from "./NewBSBtnFunc"


     export default class BSBtn extends Component {

     render() {
       return (
          <div>
            <Button onClick={NewBSBtnFunc}>Click Me</Button>
            <div id="newBtnSpace"></div>
          </div>
       )
      }
```

}

App.js

```
     import React from 'react';
     import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
     import BSBtn from "./components/BSBtn"


     function App() {
      return (
       <div>
        <BSBtn></BSBtn>
      </div>
     );
    }

   export default App;
```

github link: https://github.com/mollygilbert389/testingBootstrapBtn

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally show the new button by setting a state item (in this case `showNewButton`) to `true` in the `onClick` of the original button.

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={() => this.setState({ showNewButton: true }))}>Click Me</Button>
                <div id="newBtnSpace">{ this.state.showNewButton && <Button variant="primary" id="newBtn">New Button</Button> }</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

PS you've already successfully worked out how to create Bootstrap buttons in jsx:

```
<Button onClick={NewBSBtnFunc}>Click Me</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying to do this with a show/hide method. Needs to be created dynamically. With show/hide I'd need to hard code the button in there. Trying to get it to create buttons based off an array of words.

Comment: You don't need to hard code the button in there at all. For example: `words.map(word => <Button>{word}</Button>);`

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` does not expect a return value so returning the new button won't do anything.

The way you have things organized makes it very difficult since you can't return anything from the function, and you can't modify state from outside the class. I would suggest moving your click handler into the component and using to to modify a state value that will show the second button.

Here is my suggestion:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'reactstrap'

export default class BSBtn extends Component {
  state = {show: false}

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</Button>
        <div id="newBtnSpace">
          {this.state.show ? 
            <Button variant="primary" id="newBtn">New Button</Button>
          : null}
         </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Updated solution to your updated question:

```js
class BSBtn extends React.Component {
  state = {
    show: false,
    buttons: []
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show })
  }
  
  handleAdd = () => {
    this.setState({ buttons: [...this.state.buttons, (this.state.buttons.length + 1)] })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Option 1</h3>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
        <div id="newBtnSpace">
          {this.state.show ? [1,2,3].map((value) => (
            <div>
              <button>Button {value}</button>
            </div>
         ))
         : null}
         </div>
         <hr/>
         <div style={{ marginTop: '30px' }}>
          <h3>Option 2</h3>
          <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Click Me</button>
          {this.state.buttons.map((value) => (
            <div>
              <button>Button {value}</button>
            </div>
         ))}
         </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<BSBtn />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```

Comment: Thanks, as stated I am not trying to show or hide I want to dynamically create specifically a Bootstrap button. Trying to create a button based off names in an array, with the show method it needs to be hard coded in here.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question some more. What is the desired output? Do you wan't the whole array of buttons to show when you click the first button? Do you want a button added for every click?

Comment: Also just as a tip: There's rarely a need to use `createElement`. Just use JSX.